# How should I practice stretched chords?

Tags: guitar, technique, chords

How do you play this chord? Any tips? Which fingers should I position first? Especially hard is stretch between 2nd and 4th finger. How to avoid 3rd finger muting G string?

[image: F]

Answer (score 3):

Chords like this are all about precision with where you place your fingers. The 1st fret F barre chords are always the hardest because being so close to the nut means string tension is at its highest. This particular chord looks difficult, impractical and potentially a little silly to me. You're going to look like you're pulling the `|nn|` heavy metal horns while playing it.

If it were me, I'd try and mute the A string a little using my index finger, and the B string using the bottom edge of my middle finger.

It seems to me that this chord would be a much more suitable alternative, you've got the root doubled like your example (although you're missing the low F bass note) and the third doubles like your example.

```
5-----
-6----
5-----
--7---
---8--
------
```

At the end of the day, chords with large stretches like those will just take time to get under your fingers, and consistent finger/fret placemenet is key while practicing them - avoid any and all fret buzz with chords that low!

Also, lighter gauge strings are going to make chords like this easier to play! You won't do yourself any favours by stringing your guitar up with No 8 fencing wire.

Answer (score 0):

I'm from Brazil and I was into Bossa Nova for a while. I'm not a *great* player but I can play must "radio" musics by ear and all.

The chords I've found in Bossa Nova songs were unbelievable hard to keep up. Both right hand and left hand. I don't know what kind of music you're into. But give some Bossa a try. I bet you know "The Girl From Ipanema".

I'll send you two links that have the must accurate tabs I've seen. Besides practicing stretching, you'll notice some patterns in the chords itself and, hopefully, will be playing along in no time.

[Bossa Nova Guitar Transcriptions](http://www.etc.ch/%7Ejason/tabs.html)

[Bossa Nova Guitar](http://www.bossanovaguitar.com/bossa_nova_song_lyrics.html)

Unfortunately, both sites are not updated anymore. But give it a shot.